Did Evangelist Luke attach more importance to Jesus' Ministry than to the Nativity in description of historical background?
We see Luke at 3:1-2 (KJV) giving a definitive description of the government of the territory where John the Baptist heralded the Ministry of Jesus:

Now in the fifteenth year of the reign of Tiberius Caesar, Pontius Pilate being governor of Judaea, and Herod being tetrarch of Galilee, and his brother Philip tetrarch of Ituraea and of the region of Trachonitis, and Lysanias the tetrarch of Abilene,
Annas and Caiaphas being the high priests, the word of God came unto John the son of Zacharias in the wilderness.

In so far as the time of Nativity is concerned , the Evangelist gives the following narration in Lk 2:1-2:

And it came to pass in those days, that there went out a decree from Caesar Augustus that all the world should be taxed.(And this taxing was first made when Cyrenius was governor of Syria.)

Luke is thought to have written the Gospel sometime between 80-90 AD by which time the rulers   and administrators of Jesus' time   had changed . From the perspective of accurate linking of the Lord's life and Ministry to historical background, it was expedient to give definitive narration of who ruled where.
But then, Luke gives only a passing reference  to the historical background when it comes to the Nativity. It it that Luke attached more importance to Jesus' Ministry than to the Nativity in description of historical background  of the respective events ? What is the take of Bible scholars on such a possibility ?

Each of the Evangelists had a different emphasis because each wrote for a different audience and different purpose; thus they selected incidents to serve their individual purposes.

Look at the beginning of Luke 3 - much very accurate historical information given especially exact dates.

That is right, Dottard. I am comparing two different narratives of Luke himself . Luke is thought to have been a disciple of Paul and a physician by profession. Perhaps, Theophilus to whom Luke addressed the Gospel narratives, may have been a historian.

See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/62070/did-jesus-pay-to-reserve-the-upper-room/62074#62074
and https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/73178/what-is-the-connection-between-bethlehem-being-josephs-own-city-and-joseph-be/73183#73183

How do you explain such a late date for Luke considering the ending of Acts?
https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/34572/how-possible-is-it-that-the-gospel-of-luke-and-acts-were-written-for-paul-s-defe

It seems to me that to calculate correctly we need to include not only the birth of Jesus but also his conception. If we do this, then Luke gives more attention to the historical background of the birth narrative story than the OP indicates.

In 1:5 Luke begins the Nativity narrative with the statement "In the days of Herod, King of Judea, there was a priest named Zechariah."

At 1:8 Luke then turns to the story of Zechariah's call, which took place "when he was serving as priest in his division’s turn before God, according to the practice of the priestly service, he was chosen by lot to enter the sanctuary of the Lord to burn incense."

At 1:26, sixth months later, after Elizabeth is already pregnant with John the Baptist, Luke switches the scene to Nazareth, where he tells the story of the Annunciation to Mary.

At verse 39, Mary complies with the angel's direction and travels to Zechariah's home. She returns several months later to Nazareth, already pregnant.


So Luke gives numerous background details about the government of Judea under Herod, the administration of the Temple, the call of Zechariah and the miraculous conception of both John and Jesus. Then, in Chapter 2, Luke gives additional historical background in terms of the Roman administration.
Conclusion:  It is only natural that Luke would pay more attention to Jesus' ministry than his birth in his version of the gospel. However, since Luke gives substantial details about the government of the territory where John the Baptist and Jesus were conceived and born, it cannot be said that Luke pays more attention to Jesus' ministry than his nativity in terms of historical background.
